# Should this tag be removed in the main site?

Tags: support

I found a tag in the main site called "s". Should this tag be used?

Comment: What do you mean by "main" site. Do you mean Stack Overflow. I don't see an "s" tag in SP.SE.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/37086/2688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this tag should be deleted. If no questions reference it, I have a feeling it will get automatically deleted.

Comment: Yep, it'll be deleted within 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Thought so. It's gone now.